# django-background-tasks process_tasks not working

Tags: python, django

I've set up a django project with the instructions from the docs, and have a simple task:

```
@background
def test_task():
    print("wtf")
```

I then ran the test_task() function within the manage.py shell, and the task was successfully added to the DB (SQLite3). However, when I ran `python manage.py process_tasks` nothing happened.

This module isn't very popular to say the least, so I couldn't find any answers to my problem until 5 minutes ago on a [closed issue](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/issues/74) on the module's repository on github. And I am deciding to post this below.

PS: I am running Django 2.2 for this project

Answer (score 0):

So, I am reasonably certain the problem lies within the module's hability to discover a task. The solution was to just import the task's function in another file called tasks.py in the same folder.

Inside tasks.py:

`from .views import test_task`

Answer (score 0):

The function is placed in **tasks.py** file as this file is find using auto.discovery and trying to place this file in app where **views.py** is available

> @background
> def test_task():
> print("wtf")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).